# Getting a method not found in class, when I already have the method declared?

Tags: java, netbeans

I'm trying to create objects of the classes I have in the main method, I'm implementing the lazy simpleton pattern, but I keep getting the error cannot find symbol  in class. I've checked to see if I've written the import package statements correctly as well.

This is my main class

```
package control;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import model.ApplicationModel;
import java.util.* ;
import model.Shop;
import view.ApplicationViewer;
import model.ApplicationModel;

public class ApplicationControl {
   public static void main (String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException{

       ApplicationModel apm = new ApplicationModel.getInstance();

   }

    }
```

This is my Singleton class ApplicationModel

```
package model;
// needed for ArrayLists
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;
import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger; 

public class ApplicationModel {
  private static ApplicationModel instance = null;

    private ApplicationModel()
    {

    }
       public static ApplicationModel getInstance (){
  if (instance == null){
            instance = new ApplicationModel();
        }
        return instance;
 }

    private List<Shop> shops = new ArrayList<Shop>();
    public List<Shop> getShops(){
        return this.shops;
    }

    public void setShops(List<Shop> shops){
       this.shops = shops;
    }

    public Shop createShop(String csvString){
        String[] attributes = csvString.split(",");
        Shop shop = new Shop(attributes[0],attributes[1],attributes[2],
                attributes[3],attributes[4]);
        return shop;
        }

    public List<Shop> readShops(String shopFileName){

            ApplicationModel am = new ApplicationModel();
            List<Shop> shopList = new ArrayList<>();
            try{
            Scanner naughty = new Scanner(new File(shopFileName));
            if (naughty.hasNext()) naughty.nextLine();
            while(naughty.hasNext()){
            shopList.add(am.createShop(naughty.nextLine()));
            }
            } catch (FileNotFoundException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(ApplicationModel.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
            return shopList;
        }

    public String printShops(){
        String listOfShops ="";
        for(Shop shop : shops ){
        listOfShops = listOfShops +'\n'+ shop.toString().trim() + '\n';
        }
         return listOfShops.trim();
        }
}
```

Whenever I type in ApplicationModel in the main class, the import statement error stating that the import has not been used goes away too, I'm not sure what's wrong (I'm using netbeans). Can anyone help?

Comment: where is the header of your class, i mean `class ApplicationModel{..}` ?

Comment: `ApplicationModel apm = new ApplicationModel.getInstance();` whats the `new` supposed to do?

Comment: @tkausl do you not create a new instance of a singleton class? It's a new object I created.

Comment: @YCF_L I've edited the question and added in the header.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove "`new`" from your code:

```
ApplicationModel apm = ApplicationModel.getInstance();
```

Being `static`, `getInstance()` is a *class* method (not an instance method). This syntax is how you call class methods.

Comment: @dom try recompiling/building your project. You may be using classes built from old code even though you are looking at new code

Comment: Recompiled it twice, first time commentating the errors, and the second time with the errors copied and pasted. Still no result. Think it might be an IDE problem?

Comment: Switched my IDE to IntelliJ and it works fine there.

Comment: @dom very often when you're pulling your hair out wondering why the code you're looking at doesn't match what the code is doing when executed, the IDE not auto-compiling is the reason.

Comment: any recommendations, based on experience for a faster more reliable IDE?

Comment: @dom IMHO IntelliJ is the bomb, and the best coders I've met IRL prefer IntelliJ. I won't use anything else.